# Download a file without stop inside a service (Not IntentService)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-download-manager

I have a download service which extends Service , How can I download a file inside it such that if I remove the app from the recently apps , it continue to download file?
Now, if I remove the app from recent apps , it stops the downloading :

part of code :

```
public class downloadService extends Service {


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
    //                publishProgress((int) ((total * 1000) / lenghtOfFile));
    //                mInfo.getProgressBar().setProgress((int) ((total * 1000) / lenghtOfFile));
    //                prog = (int) ((total * 1000) / lenghtOfFile);

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    sendMessage(downloadId, (int) ((total * 1000) / lenghtOfFile));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user removes your app from 'recently running apps', the app's process gets terminated and hence your `Service` will also stop immediately. There is nothing I'm aware of that can be done to stop this from happening as of now. However, your `Service` can return something like `START_STICKY` in its `onStartCommand()` which may restart the `Service`. There, you yourself should handle the restart scenario (like restarting the download, etc.)

Like OP mentioned, we can also try to do `startForeground()` on a `Service` taking cues from the Play Store app. This can be done using:

```
int NOTIF_ID = 0;
Notification notification = ...
    .build(); // notification instance
startForeground(NOTIF_ID, notification)
```

Comment: when download starts , i want to show it in notifications and continue downloading even if app removed from recently apps , smething like startForeground for donload not for notification

Comment: Like GooglePlay , if you click downloading an app , it comes to notifications and if you remove the app from recently apps , it continues downloading in notifications

Comment: Okay .. so did you try `startForeground()`?

Comment: I just can use it for notification messages, can you give me a  biref code example?

Comment: @DavidOli Just within the `onStartCommand()` of your `Service` and to stop it, call `stopForeground(true)` before calling `stopSelf()`